# MySQL FTS boolean mode operator customizing

Tags: mysql, search, boolean, full-text-search

I'm using the InnoDB FTS of MySQL 5.6.10 and want to change the default behavior of the boolean operators.

> Note In implementing this feature, MySQL uses what is sometimes referred to as implied Boolean logic, in which
>
> [+] stands for AND
>
> [-] stands for NOT
>
> [no operator] implies OR

My desired behavior:

- [no operator] implies AND
- [|] stands for OR

> **ft_boolean_syntax**
>
> Command-Line Format   --ft_boolean_syntax=name Option-File
>   Format    ft_boolean_syntax Variable Name ft_boolean_syntax Variable
>   Scope Global Dynamic Variable Yes     Permitted Values Type   string
>   Default   +-><()~*:""& The list of operators supported by boolean
>   full-text searches performed using IN BOOLEAN MODE. See Section
>   12.9.2, “Boolean Full-Text Searches”.
>
> The default variable value is '+ -><()~*:""&|'. The rules for changing
>   the value are as follows:
>
> Operator function is determined by position within the string.
>
> The replacement value must be 14 characters.
>
> Each character must be an ASCII nonalphanumeric character.
>
> Either the first or second character must be a space.
>
> No duplicates are permitted except the phrase quoting operators in
>   positions 11 and 12. These two characters are not required to be the
>   same, but they are the only two that may be.
>
> Positions 10, 13, and 14 (which by default are set to “:”, “&”, and
>   “|”) are reserved for future extensions.

So I tried to change ft_boolean_syntax to ' |-><()~*:""&+' but that doesn't work for me. No given operator still implies OR.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the InnoDB FTS is yet half-baked. With MySQL 5.6.10 and MyISAM the customized ft_boolean_syntax works just as desired. The Boolean OR has to be expressed as '|word1 |word2' though, i.e. 'word1 | word2' will produce an AND.